# Não consigo inserir uma DropDown box em C# .Net Core, dá erro de conversão de tipo?

Tags: c#, .net

Erro:

> RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

O Model:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectList> Emails { get; set; }
```

O Controller:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
  var mls =
    (from geral in _context.Clientes
      orderby geral.Email
      select new { text = geral.Email, value = geral.Email }).ToList();
   ViewBag.MailList = mls.AsEnumerable();
  return View();
}
```

O `View`:

```
<select asp-for="Emails" asp-items="@ViewBag.MailList"></select>
```

O erro aparece no view, se eu mandar um objeto null até que aparece a caixa de seleção vazia. Já tentei todo tipo de conversão e nada, alguém tem alguma luz?

Comment: cade o codigo da view

Comment: não apareceu a parte do view:..

<select asp-for="Emails" asp-items="@ViewBag.MailList"></select>

Comment: eu arrumei. Edudemar, o tipo não está conforme esta sendo enviado para View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro acontece porque está sendo enviado o tipo errado para `View`, faça essa declaração `new SelectList` e passe as propriedades conforme são exigidos e ao ser enviado a sua `View` o tipo já está correto para ser utilizado.

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var mls = (
        from geral in _context.Clientes
        orderby geral.Email
        select new { text = geral.Email, value = geral.Email }
    ).ToList();

   ViewBag.MailList = new SelectList(mls, "value", "text");

   return View();
}
```

ou seja, faltou a declaração do tipo certo e reconhecido pelo código da sua `View`.

<sup>***Referencias***</sup>

- [SelectList Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)
- [SelectListItem Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)
- [Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49451785/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-collections-generic-listinventorylocatio)

Comment: Agradeço a atenção, funcionou a parte do controller, mas a parte do view tive que fazer de forma alternativa... meio POG, mas tudo bem, funcionou.
eu gostaria de usar:
<select asp-for="Name" asp-items="@ViewBag.MailList"></select>
mas ele deu a lista abaixo da caixa de escolha, tive que fazer o seguinte:
                @{
                  foreach (var j in ViewBag.MailList)
                  {
                    <option value="@j.Value">@j.Text</option>
                  }
                }
aí funcionou.

Valeu!!!!

Comment: Na `View` não precisa fazer nada @EudemarTonatto fez assim no Controller já é suficiente